# Float two divs containing images next to each other and auto scale

Tags: html, css

I have been trying to figure this out for a while now and can't seem to get it working. Basically I want to have two images next to each other with maybe 10-15 pixels between them. If the `imageContainer` changes in size the images should shrink but still remain next to each other. I have googled around for this to try and find the answer but none of them are working in this case. Can anyone help me figure out what I am missing. Here is a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/dcksh6wf/2/

```css
.container {
    width: 100%;
}

.imageContainer {
    width: 5%;
    max-width: 12%;
}

.image {
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
}

.image img {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="imageContainer">
        <div class="image"><img src="http://placekitten.com/105/105" /></div>
        <div class="image"><img src="http://placekitten.com/105/105" /></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you upload a rough mockup, what exactly u want ? Simple pen n paper mockup.

Comment: Why the painfully small widths on .imageContainer?

Comment: I just threw a number in there. really no reason why its that small

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to apply rules for inline display to `.image` instead of `.imageContainer`.

```css
.container {
    width: 100%;
}

.image {
    width: 5%;
    max-width: 12%;
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 10px;
}

.image img {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}

.image:first-child {
    margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="imageContainer">
        <div class="image"><img src="http://placekitten.com/105/105" /></div>
        <div class="image"><img src="http://placekitten.com/105/105" /></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this: http://plnkr.co/edit/5OJf9yQtIE7PmA4PcWEw?p=preview

```
 <div class="imageContainer">
        <div class="image"><img src="http://placekitten.com/105/105" /></div>
    </div><div class="imageContainer">
        <div class="image"><img src="http://placekitten.com/105/105" /></div>
    </div>

.container {
    width: 100%;
}

.imageContainer {
  display: inline-block;
  max-width: 50%;
}

img {
  max-height: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

The images will scale up to 50% available width, or their natural width (i.e. their resolution).